# UEFI boot order on

Tags: boot

I'm trying to replace Win8 with Ubuntu 12.04.3 server by booting via USB boot stick. I disabled UEFI but am not sure what needs to be done in UEFI boot priority setting.  The BIOS screen says "USB Boot" is [enabled]; but the "UEFI Boot priority order" shows "Windows Boot Manager", and then "EFI Network 0 for IPv4".  Those are the only 2 options.  Rebooting as is with these settings just boots into Win8.

Answer (score 0):

You should list your server's hardware version and some detail here.

I googled and found a solution, may be it can help.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/325445-30-boot-priorities-bios#.

Comment: Sorry, I just purchased it - Lenovo IdeaPad S210 4GB/500GB BIOS V3.6 EC V2.4.  Thanks for the link.